# Java: I don't get the messages from other clients?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, client, message

does anyone know whats wrong with my code?
When I write something with client1 i just see it on the server and on the client1 but not on client2.

run() in Client.java:

```
public void run() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            Socket client = new Socket(host, port);

            System.out.println("client started");

            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String i = input.nextLine();
                writer.write(clientname + ": " + i + newline);
                writer.flush();

                String s = null;

                while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(s);

                }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            client.close();

        }
```

If you need the Server code or anything else just ask.
Thanks in advance!!

Additionally the Server:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 40480;
        int max = 10;

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max);

        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.print("server started" + "\n");

            while(true) {

                try {
                    Socket client = server.accept();

                    executor.execute(new Handler(client));

                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

And the Handler:

```
public class Handler implements Runnable{

    private Socket client;

    public Handler(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String s = null;

            while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                writer.write(s + "\n");
                writer.flush();

                System.out.println(s);

            }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            client.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e) {


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes we do need to server code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example - it is not complete but should give you an idea how you could multicast output to a number of listening clients. There are better ways to do this, but I wrote it similar to how you appeared to be doing the sockets. It also lacks error checking in many places and I have left that as an exercise for the reader. This code was also written so that it can be used on Java 1.6 or higher.

The code uses a list of connected Clients maintained in the Server object. When input is received from one client, the output is multicast to each client in the Client list. Writing is done via a write method in the Client class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MulticastEchoServer {
    List<Client> clientList = new LinkedList<Client>();
    ExecutorService executor;

    int port = 40480;
    int max = 10;

    public MulticastEchoServer() {
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max);
    }

    public void writeToAllClients(String string) throws IOException {
        // Multiple threads access this so it must be in synchronized block
        synchronized (this.clientList) {
            Iterator<Client> iter = this.clientList.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext())
                iter.next().write(string);
        }
    }

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        // Multiple threads access this so it must be in synchronized block
        synchronized (this.clientList) {
            clientList.add(client);
        }
    }

    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        // Multiple threads access this so it must be in synchronized block
        synchronized (this.clientList) {
            clientList.remove(client);
        }
    }

    public void listen() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("server started and listening for connections");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    System.out.print("connection accepted" + "\n");

                    Client newClient = new Client(this, socket);

                    this.addClient(newClient);
                    this.executor.execute(newClient);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MulticastEchoServer().listen();
    }

    private class Client implements Runnable {

        Socket socket;
        PrintWriter writer;
        BufferedReader reader;
        MulticastEchoServer server;

        public Client(MulticastEchoServer server, Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.server = server;
            this.socket = socket;
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream());
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }

        synchronized public void write(String string) throws IOException {
            writer.write(string);
            writer.flush();
        }

        public void close() {
            this.writer.close();
            try {
                this.reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            try {
                this.socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Client Waiting");

            String inString = null;
            try {
                while ((inString = this.reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    this.server.writeToAllClients(inString + "\n");
                    System.out.println(inString);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }

            server.removeClient(this);
            this.close();
            System.out.println("Client Closed");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your handler:

`while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(s + "\n");
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println(s);
            }`

You are only writing the string back to the sender, not to all connected sockets

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Your server would have to maintain a list of clients. Then when the server receives data from the client the server would have to loop through all the clients and issue a write to each of them.

Comment: take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html

Comment: Sorry if I ask too much but I got absolutely stuck here! Can you give an example?

Comment: @Jonathan create a List<Socket> or a List<PrintStream> and add all of your connections to server this List. Then, where you are writing back to client, write to all sockets instead.

Comment: So i have a `List<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();` and after the `Socket client = server.accept` a `clients.add(client);`
But what to do next? Do i have to put a for loop anywhere in the Handler?