# C# Chat clients with multiple threads (read+write at the same time)

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, chat

How do I make the client read from the stream (for messages of other clients sent to the stream) at the same time as being able to write to them?

I tried creating different threads on the client side (did I even do it right?), however I can still only write to the server, without any response. This is what I'm getting right now:

(Server-Client-Client)

[image]

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace Klientas
{
    class Klientas
    {
        public static void Write()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 1000);
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(clientSocket.GetStream());
                writer.Write(str);
            }
        }
        public static void Read()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 1000);
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args){
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(Write);
            Thread ctThread2 = new Thread(Read);
            ctThread2.Start();
            ctThread.Start();

           }
    }    
}
```

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace MultiServeris
{
    class Multiserveris
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(1000);          
            ServerSocket.Start();                                    

            Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();       
                handleClient client = new handleClient();                      
                client.startClient(clientSocket);
            }


        }
    }

    public class handleClient
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;                                   
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(Chat);                   
            ctThread.Start();
        }



        private void Chat()
        {                  
            while (true)
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: You need to maintain the clients list on the server.

Comment: Use `SignalR`, it'll make your life infinitely easier.

Comment: Although the sample code I wrote for this [Stackoerflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769206/java-i-dont-get-the-messages-from-other-clients) was in Java for a similar problem, one could adapt it for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you do not have any code on the server to send messages to the client. You need to maintain a list of connected clients and make the server send a message to the eligible clients when it receives a message. Also do not make the client a console app. Unlike most projects for a chat client it is actually harder to do it as a console app.

To keep a list of clients you declare a list of TCP Clients like this

```
static List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();
```

Then when a client connects you add it to the list

```
TcpClient clientSocket = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();  
clients.Add(clientSocket);
```

Then when you receive a message you send it to all clients

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
while(true)
{
    string message = reader.ReadString();
    foreach(var client in clients)
    {
        //send message to client
    }
}
```

Now remember that in practice you should handle things like disconnects and adding and removing clients from the list should be thread safe (locks and all).

Comment: Oh, so the clients themselves cannot just keep reading the stream? How should I create the client list? Any basic examples? I just need the server to send it to everyone then.

Comment: Clients can keep reading the stream. What part of my answer made you think they can't?

Comment: Well, since you said that I have to send the message to clients from the server, I guess the clients cannot act like a server and just keep reading the same stream and print it out? Which is why I don't know how to do the `//send message to client` part :D

Comment: Do it the same way you send a message from the client to the server. It is not like reading a stream jams it or something.

Comment: I'm not sure if You can still see the notifications for my comments, however, could You tell me where should the last part of the code (sending message to all clients) be? I put the list creation in the main of the server, and adding to list to the loop in the same function. However I cannot use the `foreach(var client in clients)` in  `Chat()` which is created for every user, because it's not defined. (cannot use `static List...` aswell)

Comment: You should be able to use static list field in the Program class

Comment: Would static change anything though? The `Chat()` function still wouldn't be able to see the clients list, would it? How do I 'pass' it?

Comment: If it is in another class you should access it as Program.Clients but this class is pointless as currently written. On the other hand having a class to wrap the client is not a bad idea as you will probably need additional state. You can pass the list to the constructor. Now to be honest if you have trouble passing a list of items from one place to another you should probably take a step back and relearn the basics instead of trying to build something as complex as a chat.

Answer (score 0):

Good starting point for socket client-server communication: [demo application](https://github.com/veraciousnottaken/SocketClientServerApp) and [library](https://github.com/veraciousnottaken/SocketClientServer/). Support for reconnecting, sudden client disconnect catch, message broadcasting and many more.