# Creating a Multi-threaded Java Server Chat App.

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to implement a multithreaded server chat application in Java.
This program created a thread and waits for a client to connect. Once a client is connected, it creates another thread and waits for another client to connect.

This is my `ChatServer.java`

```
package com.chat.server;



import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;



/**
 * <p>The chat server program</p>
 * This class is a Thread that recieves connection
 * from different clients and handles them is separate
 * Thread.
 *
 * @author Aditya R.Singh
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
class ChatServer extends Thread {

    private int port;                    // The port number to listen at.
    private String ip;                   // To store the IP address.
    private Socket socket;               // Socket connection with different clients.
    private InetAddress inet;            // Handling Client Address.
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;   // The server socket used by clients to connect.



    /**
     * This is solely intended for instantiation purpose.
     * 
     * @param PORT - The port number to listen for client requests
     */
    ChatServer(final int PORT) {


        /* Initiallizing all instance variables to null. */
        ip = null;
        inet = null;
        socket = null;
        serverSocket = null;

        /* Initiallizing the port number. */
        port = PORT;
    }



    /**
     * This method creates a connection between server and client.
     * 
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    private void createConnection() throws IOException {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);  // Listen to the required port. 
        socket = serverSocket.accept();         // Accept the client connection.
    }



    /**
     * This method sets the IP address.
     */
    private void setIP() {

        inet = socket.getInetAddress();
        ip = new String(inet.getHostAddress());
    }



    /**
     * This method returns the IP address.
     *
     * @return IP address.
     */
    public String getIP() {

        return ip;
    }



    /**
     * This method checks if the socket has been connected
     * with any client.
     *
     * @return True if the client has been connected, else false
     */
    public boolean isConnected() {

        if(socket == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    /**
     * This method returns the InputStream
     * from the Socket.
     * 
     * @return InputStream if Socket has been connected to the client, else null
     * @see java.io.InputStream
     */
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

        if(socket == null)
            return null;
        return socket.getInputStream();
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            createConnection();
            setIP();
        } catch(IOException exception) {

            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Server.java`:

```
package com.chat.server;



/** 
 * <p>The Server app</p> 
 * This is the controller for accepting connections.
 *
 * @author Aditya R.Singh 
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public class Server {


    /**
     * The port at which clients will connect.
     */
    public static final int PORT = 6005;          



    /**
     * For instantiation purpose.
     */
    public Server() {


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        /* Keep accepting connections. */
        while(true) {

            ChatServer chat = new ChatServer(PORT); // Connecting port.
            chat.start();

            while(!chat.isConnected())
                /* This is a false loop. Intended to keep running unless another client is not requesting to connect. */;

            System.out.println("We connected to: "+chat.getIP());   
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine.
On running the code as:

```
java com.chat.server.Server
```

it seems that the program is listening for a client to connect. But after it connects to a client, it is expected to print the IP address of the client and then create another thread for another client. But it doesn't print the IP of the client.

This is my `Client.java`:

```
package com.chat.client;



import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket socket = null;


        try {

            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6005);
            System.out.println("Socket connected.");
        } catch(IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The client ones connects to the server, must print `Socket connected`. The client does that. The client works fine:

```
java com.chat.client.Client  
Socket connected.
```

But the server app doesn't print the IP address of the client. Why so?

Comment: This [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25778305/3857942) might give you an idea of how to do a chat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not complete code

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class MultithreadedServer {

    public static final int PORT = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while(true){
                Socket connection = server.accept();
                Thread client = new ClientThread(connection);
                client.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error start server");
        }
    }

}

class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private Socket connection;

    public ClientThread(Socket connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Do communication with client
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a race condition. The line `socket = serverSocket.accept();` causes the `while(!chat.isConnected())` loop to terminate before the method 'setIP()' is been called. A quick way to verify that this is the cause of the problem is by changing this method:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    if(socket == null)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

to

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    if(socket == null || ip == null)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

In order to fix the problem, you should make sure that the code that sets the IP and the code that checks whether it's connected use the `synchronized` keyword. Also, notice that the `while(!chat.isConnected())` loop runs with no pauses, meaning that it'd take as much CPU as it's available... which is definitely not good.

Check out the link that @Michael Petch posted for a proper implementation of a chat server.